# IntegrityError: column slug is not unique

Tags: python, django

i'm studying django by tangowithdjango tutorials, and there on 7-th chapter I've stacked.

i'm trying to include a slug field in my model and override save method to make it all working. After migrate I have an integrity error.

models.py:

```
class Category(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
    views = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.name)
        super(Category, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Categories"

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Listen to the error. You have the slug attribute specified as unique, but you must have the same slug value for multiple instances of your `Category` class.

This can easily happen if you add a unique attribute column to a table that already has data, because any constant default you use will automatically break the unique constraint.

To make the migration...

You're going to need to first migrate to just add the slug-field, without specifying it as unqiue, then set a unique slug for each `Category` in the database, then you can add the unique constraint and migrate again.

Open your most recent migration in the migrations directory of your app and edit the line that looks similar to

```
migrations.AddField(
    model_name='category',
    name='slug',
    field=models.SlugField(unique=True),
    preserve_default=False,
),
```

so that it is just

```
migrations.AddField(
    model_name='category',
    name='slug',
    field=models.SlugField(null=True, blank=True),
    preserve_default=False,
),
```

Then run the migration with `python manage.py migrate` (if you're using django 1.7. Otherwise use South for migrations), then open the django shell with `python manage.py shell`, import your Category model and run

```
for cat in Category.objects.all():
    cat.slug = cat.name
    cat.save()
```

This will set the slug for each category to be the category's name. Now, assuming all names are unique, you can create your migrations again and successfully migrate so that the DB will force unique slugs.

Comment: i was added a '' default value to it,  how can i easily fix it?

Comment: It takes some work adding a unique field to a table that already contains data. I edited my post to try and help you through it. You need to first migrate to add the field, then set a unique value for the field for each row in the table, then you can migrate again to add the uniqueness constraint

Comment: Thanks a lot! you make me understand this "slugy" question.

Comment: You should also specify NULL = true, otherwise the migrate to add slug field will also failed.

Comment: but, how to run this multiple line for loop in shell?

Comment: @DingxinXu: `for cat in Category.objects.all(): cat.slug=cat.name; cat.save();` and don't forget to import Category as `from rango.models import Category` before this